# How can I resize a TreeView during runtime in a Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resize, treeview

I am trying to resize my `TreeView` window during runtime and I cant do it.
in my program  I can press on a button and the `TreeView` opens as a popup window.

The `TreeView` is inside a `Control`:

```
private Control parent;  

mytree= new TreeView();
parent.Controls.Add(mytree);
```

I have already tried to search for any resize properties but no luck, I can't find a way that the tree will be resizable during runtime.
The only way I can see it is to delete the control and to put it in a `Form` and then I can make it look like the same but I still want to know if there is another way to solve this, please if someone knows !
 thank you

Comment: That snippet is not setting any of the properties.  Like Size.

Comment: Either directly by Size or by Anchoring or By Docking and maybe putting it into a SplitContainer..

Answer (score 0):

Assign anchor property to tree view so it resizes with form (or maybe control he is child of)

Here is example of anchoring button:

```
// Add a button to a form and set some of its common properties.
private void AddMyButton()
{
   // Create a button and add it to the form.
   Button button1 = new Button();

   // Anchor the button to the bottom right corner of the form
   button1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);

   // Assign a background image.
   button1.BackgroundImage = imageList1.Images[0];

   // Specify the layout style of the background image. Tile is the default.
   button1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;

   // Make the button the same size as the image.
   button1.Size = button1.BackgroundImage.Size;

   // Set the button's TabIndex and TabStop properties.
   button1.TabIndex = 1;
   button1.TabStop = true;

   // Add a delegate to handle the Click event.
   button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

   // Add the button to the form.
   this.Controls.Add(button1);
}
```

Important part is `button1.Anchor` where in example button is anchored to bottom right of window, so it will just follow window as you resize, but you can anchor to all sides of window and it will resize with it.

Try different things and you will figure it out.
SOURCE: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx)